# Video Blocked in Chrome - Ran Insecure content from Video Provider

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, insecure-connection

I am trying to Embed a video from this URL:-

```
http://www.mckinsey.com/videos/video?vid=2548877464001&plyrid=2399849255001&Height=270&Width=480
```

It's a public video and the embed code it gives me is following:-

```
<object id="flashObj" width="480" height="270" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0"><param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /><param name="flashVars" value="videoId=2548877464001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mckinsey.com%2FVideos%2Fvideo%3Fvid%3D2548877464001%26plyrid%3D2399849255001%26Height%3D270%26Width%3D480&playerID=1971702156001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABywrPJyk~,MP34hwWOTrPs3yLiJKkINM_zsiFWIvnW&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" /><param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" /><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=2548877464001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mckinsey.com%2FVideos%2Fvideo%3Fvid%3D2548877464001%26plyrid%3D2399849255001%26Height%3D270%26Width%3D480&playerID=1971702156001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABywrPJyk~,MP34hwWOTrPs3yLiJKkINM_zsiFWIvnW&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="480" height="270" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed></object>
```

When I try to Embed/Run it on my `HTTPS` site, it shows me a blank space with following error:-

```
[blocked] The page at https://mysite.com ran insecure content from http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1
```

Is there anyway I can fix it. It runs great in Safari and FireFox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That isn't the link to the video, thats the link to the site.
2. You're embedding an HTTP link in a page loaded on HTTPS. Load the video using an HTTPS link rather than an HTTP link.

Answer (score 0):

Your link `http://www.mckinsey.com/videos/video?vid=2548877464001&plyrid=2399849255001&Height=270&Width=480`is not the video link. It's just the website where the video is. Try finding the video link from the website. and refer to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error message occur before when the page is loaded on HTTPS but other content is loaded from HTTP. Get both the page's URL and the content to load on the same protocol to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting in none-encrypted data on an encrypted site, witch can cause browsers to throw errors.

What I would do is just go and grab [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and use that to embed the video instead. It should be able to handle any kind of browser related issues without much fuss.